# Physical meaning of the Wilson Loops as spin impurities

Tags: gauge-theory, wilson-loop

This is in reference to the paper of David Tong [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.6167.pdf). In this paper in section 2, it says

> In this first section, we explain how spin impurities, coupled to bulk gauge fields, can
> be thought of as Wilson lines.

Can anyone explain to me what are spin impurities exactly and how can they couple to the gauge field? Is there a gravitational analogue of such 'impurities' coupling to the connection?